# Netlogo - agent travels along the link

Tags: netlogo

I am modelling another project concerning the warehouse operations. In this particular instance, I have to visualize the warehouse layout of the storage space. I plan to define a number of links as routes where the agents (forklift truck) can travel along with in the warehouse.

For each link, there is a distance associated with. It’s not the link length as the distance but a distance attributes user defined. If I set a forklift truck driving speed, how do I reflect it accurately in the model with the use of command like fd (or forward) and jump. How do I specify the unit of measure in jump or fd in association with the distance defined in the link to ensure the forklift truck is moving in a correct distance per tick given the speed and distance.

A simple demo would be highly appreciated! Great thanks!

Comment: Presumably your warehouse is represented in the NetLogo world. Like a map, each patch would then have a scale compared to the real world warehouse. Let's say a patch is 10x10 metres. Similarly, each tick represents some unit of time, let's say 1 minute. If the forklift speed is 6 km/h, then it can go 100m per minute, so 10 patches per tick.

Comment: thanks. that's exactly what I am doing.

Comment: then what's your question?

Comment: I just figured out before you answer me. This question can be closed. (I have another new question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205963/netlogo-add-one-more-digit-to-the-string-automatically)